# Core Audio: Audio Unit to boost signal level

Tags: ios, audio, boost, core-audio, avaudiosession

Our VOIP app uses both the Voice Processing IO Unit and the Remote IO Unit (we rebuild the AUGraph depending on which IO unit we require). We've noted that the audio output level is not as loud as some other VOIP apps such as Skype.

Rather than manipulating the incoming PCM data itself, I am investigating how I might insert other Audio Units into the path to boost the signal level. I have successfully experimentally used both the N-Band and Parametric EQ Audio Units to do this, but was wondering if there might be a simpler way or more appropriate audio unit for boosting the signal level?

Comment: did you ever figure it out for new iOS versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in to kAudioUnitSubType_PeakLimiter or kAudioUnitSubType_DynamicsProcessor. The limiter will do the trick.

Comment: I can recommend the kAudioUnitSubType_PeakLimiter with a reasonable gain, this should work nicely.